# How to change the value of an element in a dictionary of arrays?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have created a dictionary like this

```
var MyArray: [String:[String:[Int]]] = [
    "xx": ["x1": [1, 2, 3], "x2": [4, 5, 6], "x3": [7, 8, 9]],
    "yy": ["y1": [10, 11, 12], "y2": [13, 14, 15], "y3": [16, 17, 18]]]
```

How can I change the value "xx" to "zz"?
Tried this: `Exercises["xx"] = "zz"` but it don't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You can't change the value of Exercises["xx"] to "zz" because the values are of type [String:[Int]] and "zz" is a string. Is "zz" another entry in the Exercises dictionary?

Comment: FYI - you have only accepted an answer to one of your questions. You really need to go back to your other questions and if any answer solved your issue, you should mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: @rmaddy Okay now?  I marked the ones that helped me and answered the questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no single command for that but you can easily do that by assigning existing value to new "zz" key and then clean old entry:

```
array["zz"] = array["xx"]
array["xx"] = nil
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The value of `xx` is `["x1": [1, 2, 3], "x2": [4, 5, 6], "x3": [7, 8, 9]]` not a String.

If you want a value of `zz` in the dictionary, you can do `myArray["zz"] = myArray["xx"]` and then delete the old entry with `myArray["xx"] = nil`